# Translate NDesk.Options.OptionSet construction to PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Below is a typical `OptionSet` construction code:

```
var p = new OptionSet {
  { "h|help", "Show this help", v => { isHelp = (v != null); } },
};

var extra = p.Parse(args);
```

My Powershell version of the same code is:

```
$p = New-Object NDesk.Options.OptionSet
$p.Add("h|help", "Show this help", { param([string]$v) $global:isHelp = $true })
$extra = $p.Parse($args)
```

Unfortunately, it has two problems. When I execute the second line I get this:

```
Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Add" and the argument count: "3".
At C:\Work\hg\utils\HgTagPromotedBuild.ps1:62 char:7
+ $p.Add <<<< ("h|help", "Show this help message", { param([string]$v) $global:isHelp =
 $true })
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

then executing the next line results in:

```
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "System.Object[]", for "Parse" to type "System
.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[
]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sy
stem.String]"."
At C:\Work\hg\utils\HgTagPromotedBuild.ps1:63 char:18
+ $extra = $p.Parse <<<< ($args)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

The relevant portion of `OptionSet` declaration is:

```
public OptionSet Add(Option option);
public OptionSet Add(string prototype, OptionAction<string, string> action);
public OptionSet Add<TKey, TValue>(string prototype, OptionAction<TKey, TValue> action);
public OptionSet Add<T>(string prototype, Action<T> action);
public OptionSet Add(string prototype, Action<string> action);
public OptionSet Add<TKey, TValue>(string prototype, string description, OptionAction<TKey, TValue> action);
public OptionSet Add(string prototype, string description, OptionAction<string, string> action);
public OptionSet Add<T>(string prototype, string description, Action<T> action);
public OptionSet Add(string prototype, string description, Action<string> action);
```

I do not understand what is going on in the first error at all.

The second is clear - apparently `$args` is typed as `object[]`, while `OptionSet.Parse` expects `IEnumerable<string>`, but I cannot find how to cast to `string[]`.

So, my question is how do I translate the original C# code to Powershell without these nasty exceptions?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to all the folks who have made me understand that PowerShell has a well defined methodology for working with command line arguments. I have acknowledged this fact and have even created a dedicated SO question - [Is there a decent command line parser for powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004967/is-there-a-decent-command-line-parser-for-powershell), which I have already marked as answered. Again, thanks to all.

Now, I am still interested to know how do I invoke particular .NET code from PowerShell, if at all possible. No connection to command line argument parsing. Just pure quest for knowledge.

Comment: Can you tell what you want to achieve? Or maybe even ask a separate question on how to achieve that in PowerShell? You ask how to use a tool which is not supposed to be used in PowerShell *for PowerShell*.

Comment: Try to cast the 3rd argument to the type you need explicitly (Action<string>?). Also, in PowerShell (v2, hopefully, v3 will be different) is not quite easy to use generic methods. Take a look at this post (hope, this helps): http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/06/19/invoking-generic-methods-on-non-generic-classes-in-powershell/

Comment: And how do I cast to Action<string>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell has its own native argument/parameter parser/binder for functions and cmdlets. You can't override this with NDesk.Options, so you're pissing in the wind here I'm afraid my good man. Before you say "jeez, that sucks" you should think a bit about the larger goals of powershell. By coming with a baked-in parameter binder, function/command invocation styles are invariant: no wondering if it's slash or hyphen, doubleslash, equals, colon etc. This is the same reason why cmdlets and functions use familiar verb-noun notation in naming. Instead of guessing how to invoke things and getting it wrong, you can actually get down to the more useful activity of discovering what you can do.

What are you trying to achieve from a broader perspective? Post the desired parameter binding semantics and I will show you how to declare this in a powershell function.

**Update**: if you want to learn more about powershell, have a read through my good friend Keith Hill's free ebook: Effective Windows PowerShell, available free in PDF: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/effective-windows-powershell-the-free-ebook/

Comment: There are two goals to this question - to improve my PS skills and to be able to parse command line arguments using a familiar (and great) library. But I am not locked on NDesk.Options - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004967/is-there-a-decent-command-line-parser-for-powershell

Comment: I think you miss my point - powershell does not offer access to the raw arguments so you won't able to reliably use any other libraries. There is no equivalent of argc/argv, and this is a good thing. I'm not saying NDesk.Options is not great (it is) but it's for raw console apps.

Comment: OK, my other post has already been answered, so I get it how to deal with command line parameters in PowerShell. Let us forget about command line parsing and talk about invoking certain .NET code from PowerShell. I would like to make the code work regardless of command line arguments stuff.

Comment: You are trying to run before you can walk. Read that ebook. Casting is as simple as:  $strarray = [string[]] $arr  -- as a general guide, powershell's type coercion is much wider than c#.

Comment: I must admit I have tried casting and it did not work. But, I have figured out why. I did a stupid thing of decompiling NDesk.Options with ildasm, changing the version of mscorlib and others to 2.0.0.0 and compiling back with ilasm to make it work with PowerShell ScriptEngine, instead of simply retargeting the latter to work against .NET 4. My hack has failed miserably at run-time, because mscorlib 2.0.0.0 does not have `Func<T1,T2>` defined (although I have expected that to fail at compile time). Anyway, casting to `string[]` works fine now, but what about `MethodCountCouldNotFindBest` error?

Comment: @mark because powershell has more flexible type coercion than the c# compiler, sometimes overload resolution is ambiguous when it would not be as pure c#. You sometimes have to strongly type (early bind) arguments rather than rely on late-bound/dynamic typing.