# Is there a decent command line parser for powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

I am used to NDesk.Options, which I find both simple and powerful. But before trying to code against it in powershell I am wondering whether there is something already built in.

Thanks

Comment: Did you not believe my other answer to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand your question but as far as you want to parse script or function parameters you've got the `param` keywork as discribe in [about_Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315296.aspx), [about_Functions_Advanced](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315326.aspx),  [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347600.aspx). This will allow you to specify different restriction for parameters.

Comment: +1 You shouldn't need a separate parser to handle parameters.  It's not the PowerShell way.

Comment: An example would be very helpful.

Comment: you've got plenty of them in "about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters"